# How to make this hta create text file only once value is submitted

Tags: javascript, html, forms, text-files, hta

I have an hta file that writes to a text file using a form and some javascript.

The form's text field has id of `keyword_id` which is used by the JS, and directory is the value of the hidden field.

How do I change the JS to only create TEST.txt when user clicks submit?

The code also opens a new `C:` window everytime I click submit, what's with that?

Here is the html form & javascript code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="signup">   
        <h1>Type any keyword(s):</h1>
        <form action="/" method="post">
            <div class="top-row">
                <div class="field-wrap">
                    <label>
                        <span class="req"></span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" required autocomplete="off" id="keyword_id" />
                    <input type="hidden" name="write" value="C:\Users\ME\Desktop\TEST.txt" id="write_id"/>
                    <button type="submit" onclick="Writedata()" class="myButton"/>Auto Search</button>
               </div>
           </div>
```

**Javascript**

```
<script language="javascript">
function Writedata() {
    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var write_id;
    write_id = document.getElementById('write_id').value ;    
    var s = fso.CreateTextFile(write_id, true);    
    s.WriteLine(document.getElementById('keyword_id').value);    
    s.Close();
}
</script>
```

Comment: "... the hta file creates the text file upon launching ..." It doesn't, at least there's nothing in the posted code which would call `Writedata` at start. Also you've to call the function before submitting the form, i.e. add an onsubmit handler to form. Please show more code, currently there's not any submit button to click.

Comment: Sorry about that, you're right. It doesn't create the text file on open, but it does open C: folder in another window when a user inputs any text and submits with either button. How do I prevent this? You can view the entire hta here:  http://testsite24.netai.net/public/mainmenu.hta   Thanks Teemu!

Answer (score 1):

You've `<form action="/" method="post">` and the opened C folder is a response to the form submission.

Most likely you actually don't need the form to be submitted, hence you can omit the attributes in the `form` tag, and prevent the submission by changing the button type to `"button"`. It's also possible to prevent the default action of `button type="submit"` by doing this:

```
function Writedata () {
          :
    window.event.returnValue = false;
    window.event.cancelBubble = true;
}
```